# How to display 2 partial views by one click in MVC .Net with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Lets say I have a list of MovieNames. What I want is that when I click on one MovieName, 2 partial views will be shown. 
I have done with one partial view but I dont know how to show the second partial view.

Here is the index file:

Index.cshtml

```
@using Booking_Ticket_Management_System.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Schedule>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Schedule";
}
<h2>Choose movies</h2>

<div style="border:1px solid">
        @foreach (Schedule schedule in Model)
        {

                @Ajax.ActionLink(schedule.Movie.MovieName, "GetSchedule", "Schedule", new { MovieID = schedule.MovieID }, new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "Schedule",
                }
                )
                //@Html.RadioButton("abc",schedule.MovieID) @schedule.Movie.MovieName
            <br />
        }

</div>
<div id="Schedule" style="float:left">
This is the text that will be replaced by the contents of Partial View.
```

When I click on the Ajax.ActionLink, it displays only one partial view at one given position. I want to display 2 partial views at different positions. Please help!

Comment: Can't you just place both of those partial views on a "wrapper" partial view and call that?

Comment: at the end of first partial call render partial to render 2nd one on some condition or without condition

Comment: @intracept If it's like that, Why do I need 2 partial views.

Comment: @Ehsan The second partial view will be displayed in the first partial view, not in the base view.

Comment: Good question.  Why do you need two partial views? :)

Comment: thats what i am saying render partial inside first partial view

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I mean I want the second partial view displayed in the base view.

Comment: in the scueess call back of first you can call second partial view on some con